# declare function fetch(input?: Request | string, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;

Tags: javascript

> declare function fetch(input?: Request | string, init?: RequestInit): Promise;

what is the right way to read this I'm trying to learn JS and i would like to know what all of this means. Thank you

Comment: This is not JavaScript.  Are you looking at Babel files?

Comment: That looks like TypeScript, or perhaps some other extension of JavaScript that features optional strong typing.

Comment: Might be Flow also. Hard to tell with them being so similar. @LuisAvila: what's the context of where you're seeing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether this is TypeScript or if it's Flow, but both have very similar syntaxes.

`declare function fetch ... ;` is declaring that `fetch` is a global function so that the type system knows that it exists. This is followed by the input parameters `(input?: Request | string, init?: RequestInit)` and return type `: Promise<Response>`. (it returns a `Promise` that resolves to a `Response` object). Both `input` and `init` are trailed by a `?` meaning the parameter is *optional*. `input` has the type `Request | string` meaning it can be *either* a `Request` or a `string`, and `init` has the type `RequestInit`.

This is all a good representation of the `fetch` API, which is well documented [in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

Comment: Thank you Jacob this was excatly what I was looking for.